# Trigger do not compile

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a database that is made like this

```
works_on(ssn,project_number,hours)
```

and i have a trigger that asks me

1. that if an emp works more than 50 hours on a  project it cannot be put on a 2 project.
2. if an emp works more than 70 hours on 2 projects it cannot be associated on a 3 project
3. an emp can only be associated to a max of 6 project

Sorry for my attempt i'm just learning how to make triggers. I have an error near the select statement:

> Errore(8,6): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting
> one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null 
>      continue
> avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance
> execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date       pipe        <an alternat

My trigger so far:

```
create or replace trigger  exe
before insert on worsk_on
for each row
declare
too_much_hours EXCEPTION;
no_hours_left EXCEPTION;
 too_projects EXCEPTION;
begin
if hours>100
then  raise too_much_hours;
end if;
elsif   (select count(project_number),ssn,sum(hours) from worsk_on
where count(project_number) > 1 and (sum(hours)>100)
group by ssn,project_number)
then  raise  no_hours_left;
end if;
else  count( porject_number)>6
then raise too_projects;
end if;
EXCEPTION
when too_much_hours  then raise_application_error(-20000,'ore progetto sature');
when no_hours_left  then raise_application_error(-19000,'ore progetti sature');
when  too_projects   then raise_application_error(-15151,'ore progetti sature');
```

Comment: `end if; elsif ` => `elseif `

Comment: i'm using sql developer and if i type elseif it is not a blue word

Comment: Yes, `elsif` is a correct term. Don't terminate an `IF` statement with `END IF;` before  `ELSIF` , that's the point.

Comment: Apart from the wrong `END IF / ELSIF` syntax, your main problem is that in Oracle, in a trigger on a table (e.g. works_on), you cannot execute a `SELECT` statement on the same table (works_on).

Comment: Once resolving syntax errors and avoiding [mutating table exception](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/mutating-table-exceptions)  (see [compound trigger](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/trigger-enhancements-11gr1#compound_triggers)) then you have an issue in the exception block. Specifically  no_hours_left  and too_projects will cause Oracle to raise an *ORA-21000:  argument out of range* exception. [Raise Application Error](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS99960) must use error numbers between **-20999 and -20000**.

Answer (score 2):

There are many errors:

- You have not declared a PL/SQL `hours` variable.
- You are using `SELECT` inside an `IF` statement.
- The `SELECT` statement does not have an `INTO` clause.
- You are selecting all the `ssn` and `project_number` and do not have a filter to correlate it to the row being inserted.
- You have spelling mistakes in `worsk_on` and `porject_number`.
- The third `COUNT( project_number )` is not valid as you are not in a `SELECT` statement.
- You have `elsif` and `else` statements with no corresponding `IF` statement (as you have closed the previous statements with `END IF`.

There may be more (for example, if you fix all of them then I expect you'll get a mutating table exception as you are aggregating over the table you are inserting into.)

Comment: well i have to get the data from my tables, and see if my conditions  are satisfied.  how can i make an if with select so?  dont worry for spelling it's just a temporany translate .

Comment: @ToniRossi `SELECT` is not valid in PL/SQL unless it either has an `INTO` or `BULK COLLECT INTO` clause or is inside a cursor. You may need to get the values from your table but you are doing it incorrectly.

Comment: you are right i never did a trigger before. i'm trying to do on a db that i have. i still dont get how to get values from tables and put them into a pl/sql

Comment: _"i still dont get how to get values from tables and put them into a pl/sq"_   Take a look at the docs:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-EDB2297F-A80D-48B3-8EF1-5437BF981CC2